# Substract dates in one column by ID

Tags: r, date, for-loop, datatable, difference

I'm new to R and to this website. I tried to search on this site to find a solution to my problem but I cannot find it. My question is the following:

How can I calculate the difference between the date having a '1' ID and the previous date having a '0' ID. Then the difference between the date having a '2' ID and the previous date having ID '0', and so on? I would like to add this difference as a new column 'Difference' to my datatable.

Furthermore, I would like to have a column called 'Performed_Date' showing the dates corresponding to the IDs (1,2 and so on) when the difference is calculated between the '1' or '2' IDs and the '0' ID.

In addition, when there are no '0' IDs between ID's (ID '2' and ID '3' for example) it should calculate the difference between the highest ID ('3' in this example) and the previous date with the '0' ID.

My datatable is the following:

```
Registration  Date       ID   CBI   TBI
A118          7-3-2017   0    NA    NA
A118          8-3-2017   0    NA    NA
A118          9-3-2017   1    5     10
A118          10-3-2017  0    NA    NA
A118          11-3-2017  2    8     16
A118          12-3-2017  3    9     18
A118          13-3-2017  0    NA    NA
A118          14-3-2017  4    5     10
```

My expected output is the following:

```
Registration  Date       ID   CBI   TBI  Difference  Performed_Date
A118          7-3-2017   0    NA    NA   1           9-3-2017          
A118          8-3-2017   0    NA    NA   1           11-3-2017
A118          9-3-2017   1    5     10   2           12-3-2017
A118          10-3-2017  0    NA    NA   1           14-3-2017
A118          11-3-2017  2    8     16   
A118          12-3-2017  3    9     18
A118          13-3-2017  0    NA    NA
A118          14-3-2017  4    5     10
```

I thought it should be something with a for-loop of the ave-function, but I cannot think of something that could calculate it. Can someone please tell me how to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go,

data:

```
df<-
data.table::fread("
Registration  Date       ID   CBI   TBI
A118          7-3-2017   0    NA    NA
A118          8-3-2017   0    NA    NA
A118          9-3-2017   1    5     10
A118          10-3-2017  0    NA    NA
A118          11-3-2017  2    8     16
A118          12-3-2017  3    9     18
A118          13-3-2017  0    NA    NA
A118          14-3-2017  4    5     10")
```

code:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format="%d-%m-%Y")

nonZeroIDs <- which(df$ID != 0)
relatedIDs <- sapply(nonZeroIDs,function(x){
                  for(i in x:1) if(df$ID[i] == 0) return(i)
                  })

diffs <- df$Date[nonZeroIDs] - df$Date[relatedIDs]

result<- data.frame(Difference=diffs,Performed_Date=df$Date[nonZeroIDs])
```

result:

```
  Difference Performed_Date
1     1 days     2017-03-09
2     1 days     2017-03-11
3     2 days     2017-03-12
4     1 days     2017-03-14
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does exactly what I was looking for :)